# PHP JSON decoding - accessing object

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to extract a value from a JSON string that's in my program.  The output of var_dump($obj); is this:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["BTC"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    float(403.645)
    ["currency"]=>
    string(3) "GBP"
  }
}
```

What I want to access is the value (currently 403.645 in this example), but I can't work out how to do it.

I've tried `$obj->value` and other combinations, but get nowhere; it appears to me that this is an object inside an object and as a result I can't find out how to access it.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A JSON string? Have you tried json_decode()?

Comment: Thanks Rooster - seems completely obvious now you've pointed it out!  I'd tried a bunch of stuff, but not that! :-)